# Parameters for using sigmoidal fit in python

Tags: python-2.7

I used

```
y = c / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0))) + y0
```

in python to fit a sigmoid into a curve with points. Can any one tell me what the parmeter "c" means in sigmoidal fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula for sigmoid is `1 / {1 + e**(-x)}` and has the following curve:

[image]

In general, this curve is squashed between the range `[0, 1]`.

---

Now, `c` is a scaling factor. Multiplying the curve by `c` results in the upper bound of the curve increasing.

[image]

As you can see, this curve has the range `[0, 10]` on the y-axis.

---

Finally, we'll consider `y0`, which is the offset factor, with respect to the x-axis. Putting it all together, the curve `c / (1 + e ** -x) + y0` looks something like

[image]

[Try it out yourself.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D++10+%2F+(+1+%2B+e%5E-x)+%2B+10,+x+%3D+-5+to+5)